# Pandas read XML with child elements

Tags: pandas, xml

i have following XML file:

```
<ANSWER>
  <ROW TYPE="data" VALUE="abc">
     <START ID="123" U="xyz"></START>
     <END ID="321" U="zyx"></END>
   </ROW>
   <ROW TYPE="data" VALUE="def">
     <START ID="456" U="xyz"></START>
   </ROW>
   <ROW TYPE="data" VALUE="ghi">
     <START ID="789" U="xyz"></START>
     <END ID="987" U="zyx"></END>
   </ROW>
</ANSWER>
```

I need to parse it to pandas df, where each attribute will be a column in pandas df including children attributes:

| TYPE | VALUE | START ID | START U | END ID | END U |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | abc | 123 | xyz | 321 | zyx |
| data | def | 456 | ghi |  |  |
| data | ghi | 789 | xyz | 987 | zyx |

Note that not each  element contains  as a child.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This one is going to be somewhat complicated because of the structure of you xml. I'll try to explain as we go along, but you will have to read up on some of the steps:

```
#import the required libraries
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

ans = """[your xml above]"""
#parse the xml
doc = etree.XML(ans)
#prepare the structure of your df
df_rows = []
cols = ["TYPE","VALUE","START ID","START U","END ID","END U"]
#use xpath to search for you required data
answers = doc.xpath('//ANSWER')
for ans in answers:
    rows = ans.xpath('.//ROW')    
    for row in rows:    
        #initialize a list for each row in the df
        df_row = []
        #collect attribute values in each ROW and add them to the list
        df_row.extend( [item for item  in row.xpath('./@*')])

        #do the same for each attribute value in the child tags
        ent_row = []
        for entry in row.xpath('.//*'):
            ent_row.extend( [item for item in entry.xpath('./@*')])
        #flatten the collected data and add it to the df row
        df_row.extend( [item for item  in ent_row])
        #where child tags are missing, pad the row with blanks
        df_row.extend([" "] * (6 - len(df_row)))
        #append each row to the collection of df rows
        df_rows.append(df_row)

#finally, print your df
pd.DataFrame(df_rows, columns=cols)
```

Output should be your expected output.